# ASP.NET MVC - Concatenate dates in ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project in ASP.NET MVC 5. I have a ViewModel

```
    public class AcademicYearListViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Academic Year")]
    public int StartYear 
    {
        get { return this.StartDate.Year; } 
    }

    public int EndYear
    {
        get { return this.EndDate.Year; }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Start date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "End date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

In the ViewModel, I want to Extract Year from StartDate and EndDate. Then concatenate the result and seperate them by backslash. The result should be string and look like this: 2008/2009.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a getter-only property and assign it with string concatenation like these examples below:

**1) Using standard concatenation**

```
public string ConcatDate
{
    get
    {
        return StartDate.Year + "/" + EndDate.Year;
    }
}

public string ConcatDate
{
    get
    {
        return StartYear + "/" + EndYear;
    }
}
```

**2) Using `string.Format()`**

```
public string ConcatDate
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}", StartDate.Year, EndDate.Year);
    }
}
```

**3) Using string interpolation (C# 6+)**

```
public string ConcatDate
{
    get
    {
        return $"{StartYear}/{EndYear}";
    }
}
```

Demo example: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IV4bxf)

Answer (score 0):

You could add another read only property , this do the job

```
[Display(Name = "End date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Start date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "concanate")]

public string dateTime { get {
        return StartDate.Year + "/" + EndDate.Year;
    } }
```